# How to give precedence to one hook in react?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui

```
const handleSelect = (e) => {
 //do something 

}

const handleChange = (e) => {
     setChecked(e.target.checked);
}


 return (
        <Grid
            container
            direction="row"
            justify="center"
            alignItems="center">
            <TreeItem
                onLabelClick={handleSelect}
                nodeId={nodeId}
                label={
                    <div>
                        <Checkbox
                            checked={checked}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                        />
                        {literal}
                    </div>}
                onNodeToggle={handleToggle}
            >
            </TreeItem>
        </Grid>
    )
}
```

Trying to create a TreeView with a checkbox. Only issue that I've run into is that when clicking the checkbox, that also expands the tree, which is not the behavior I want.

How do I override the onLabelClick to not execute if handleChange (the checkbox) was selected?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you probably want to prevent event bubbling with [stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation).

So your handleChange function would be

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation()
    setChecked(e.target.checked);
}
```

Comment: That works, but the problem is that the TreeView onLabelClick executes first before the Checkbox on change. How do I reverse the order?

Comment: I would think the other option would be to add a check inside handleSelect. 
`const handleSelect = (e) => {
     if(checked) return;

      // do something
} `

Then you short circuit it before it does anything.